# Paypal Express Checkout page not showing up correctly in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, paypal

I just recently finish integrating PayPal Express Checkout into my clients website and while i was testing all of the features and checking for browser compatibility I would go through the checkout process in firefox, and upon landing on the Paypal Checkout Page, the page would be in a single column. Almost like the CSS file was not loading. Any tips to fix this or is this just an issue with FireFox &/or PayPal. Do I need to notify my clients customers that Paypal may not work in FireFox? Is anybody else having this issue?

Check it out for yourself if you want. Go here http://dev.mylasunusualscents.com/store.php and go through the process with firefox and then with another broswer and let me know what your results are please.

Thanks,
Dave

Answer (score 0):

Googled it came up with this ? Update your flash player
Flash Player v15.0.0.189  http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/

Comment: While the flash player in my FireFox browser needed to be updated, this was not the solution. I am thinking that it is just the Paypal Sandbox that is like this, once we go live Paypal Live will be better built.